# PySimpleGUI Listbox set focus on last item

Tags: pysimplegui

I trying after go to last item, after insert item into listbox.

I traid to use method in class Listbox(Element), but I fail ->(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/master/PySimpleGUI.py).
I apreciate if someone give me a hit, thank you.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


my_font = ("Arial", 11)
list_count = []

sg.theme('DarkAmber')


layout = [[sg.Text("Chave da NFe:")],
          [sg.Input(key='INPUT', size=(80,1), font=my_font, do_not_clear = False)],
          [sg.Text("", key="-qtd-", size=(10,1), text_color='red')],
          [sg.Listbox(values=list_count,size=(80,3), key="-lbox-")]]

window = sg.Window("Romaneio", layout, size=(600,150), finalize=True)
qtd = window['-qtd-']
lb = window['-lbox-']
entry = window['INPUT']
entry.bind("<Return>", "_RETURN")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "INPUT_RETURN":
        list_count.append(values['INPUT'])
        rst = f"Qtd: {len(list_count)}"
        qtd.update(rst)
        lb.update(list_count)

window.close()
```

Comment: Maybe this solve my question
lb.update(list_count,scroll_to_index=100)

Comment: `lb.update(list_count,scroll_to_index=len(list_count)` or `lb.Widget.yview_moveto(1)`

Comment: Very clever, thank you!!!